# Bad file descriptors when implementing pipes & execvp

Tags: c, shell, pipe, fork

I'm currently working on an assignment that is teaching us on how to implement pipes in my custom shell. Before I actually implement pipes on my shell and change my code, they want us to create two children, and run a command on each child while implementing a pipe:

Execute "ls -l" on child 1
Execute "tail -n 2" on child 2

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[]){
    int debugMode=0;
    int p[2];
    int writeDup;
    int readDup;
    int status;
    if (strcmp(argv[1],"-d")==0)
        debugMode=1;
    if (pipe(p)<0)
        return 0;
    int child1= fork();
    if (child1 == 0)
    {

        if (debugMode == 1)
            fprintf(stderr, "Child 1 is redirecting stdout to write end of pipe.\n");

        fclose(stdout);
        writeDup = dup(p[1]);
        close(writeDup);
        char *args[] = {"ls","-l",NULL};
            
        if (execvp(args[0],args)<0){
            if (debugMode ==1)
                perror("ls -l failed ");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (debugMode == 1)
            fprintf(stderr, "Parent process is waiting to close write end of pipe.\n");

        while ((child1=waitpid(-1,&status,0))!=-1);

        close(p[1]);

    }
    int child2 = fork();
    if (child2 == 0)
    {
        fclose(stdin);
        readDup = dup(p[0]);
        close(readDup);

        char *args[] = {"tail","-n","2",NULL};

        if (execvp(args[0],args)<0){
            if (debugMode ==1)
                perror("tail -n 2 failed ");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else{
        if (debugMode == 1)
            fprintf(stderr, "Parent process is closing read end of pipe.\n");

        while ((child2=waitpid(-1,&status,0))!=-1);
        close(p[0]);
    }
    if (debugMode == 1 && child1 != 0  && child2 !=0)
            fprintf(stderr, "Waiting for child processes to terminate.\n");

    while ((child1=waitpid(-1,&status,0))!=-1 && (child2=waitpid(-1,&status,0))!=-1 );

    return 0;
    
    
}
```

However, while executing, I receive several errors:

```
ls: write error : bad file descriptor
tail: cannot fstat 'standard input': Bad file descriptor
tail: -: bad file descriptor
```

They requested us to close the standard inputs & outputs, so by doing so I assume that the program should default into reading/writing into the pipe. I'm continuing to try to find a solution, I would appreciate any help or direction!

Comment: `close(writeDup);` should be `close(p[1])`. And similarly for `close(readDup)`.

Comment: Also, it's generally preferable to use `dup2()` rather than `dup()`, to ensure that you replace the desired FD.

Comment: I don't see where you ever redirect your `stdio` into the pipe.

Comment: Yeah, I came to the conclusion that I should use dup2 and close p[1]  a minute after posting because I thought to myself, "Why am I duplicating if I'm not using them?". Currently fixing that and now ls -l is in an endless loop